# Getting > web01: Destroying VM and associated drives... while running command vagrant up in gitbash

Tags: vagrant

- Getting > web01: Destroying VM and associated drives... while running
  command vagrant up in gitbash

  Can anyone help me out with this?

  Below is the error obtained while running vagrant up :
- pavan@Pavan MINGW64 /c/VISUAL PATH
  LABS/vprofile-project/vagrant/Manual_provisioning (local-setup) $
  vagrant up Bringing machine 'web01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
  Bringing machine 'app01' up with 'virtualbox' provider... Bringing
  machine 'rmq01' up with 'virtualbox' provider... Bringing machine
  'mc01' up with 'virtualbox' provider... Bringing machine 'db01' up
  with 'virtualbox' provider...    ==> web01: Importing base box
  'ubuntu/xenial64'...    ==> web01: Matching MAC address for NAT
  networking...    ==> web01: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' version
  '20211001.0.0' is up to date...    ==> web01: Setting the name of the
  VM: Manual_provisioning_web01_1639691363459_90324    ==> web01:
  Clearing any previously set network interfaces...    ==> web01:
  Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
  web01: Adapter 1: nat
  web01: Adapter 2: hostonly    ==> web01: Forwarding ports...
  web01: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)    ==> web01: Destroying VM and associated drives...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything related to Hyper-V to be enabled for this command to work? If yes windows 11 home edition does not support Hyper-V natively have to go for the pro version.